nextflow star and deseq2 pipeline - making sure *ReadsPerGene.out.tab output files become inputs
I'm making a nextflow pipeline that takes paired fastq files for a control and treatment sample, run fastqc on them, run STAR indexing and alignment, and finally run a deseq2. Im having trouble with the deseq2 part - i want to take the output of my STAR alignment processes, use only the file named *ReadsPerGene.out.tab, and use that as the input of my deseq2 process. I dont think the deseq2 process is properly recieving its input.
heres my code:
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.reads_control_1 = "./data/control/subset_control_1.fastq"
params.reads_control_2 = "./data/control/subset_control_2.fastq"
params.reads_treatment_1 = "./data/treatment/subset_treatment_1.fastq"
params.reads_treatment_2 = "./data/treatment/subset_treatment_2.fastq"
params.genome = './data/ggal/genome.fna'
params.gtf = './data/ggal/annotations.gtf'
params.star_index = './starindex'
params.output = './results'




process FASTQC {
    container 'quay.io/biocontainers/fastqc:0.12.1--hdfd78af_0'
    input:
    path reads_control_1 
    path reads_control_2 
    path reads_treatment_1 
    path reads_treatment_2

    script:
    """
    fastqc -o . $reads_control_1 $reads_control_2 $reads_treatment_1 $reads_treatment_2
    """
}


process STARINDEX {
    container 'quay.io/biocontainers/star:2.7.11b--h43eeafb_3'
    input:
    path genome
    path gtf


    output:
    path params.star_index
        
    script:
    """
    STAR --runThreadN 8 --runMode genomeGenerate \\
         --genomeDir ${params.star_index} \\
         --genomeFastaFiles $genome \\
         --sjdbGTFfile $gtf \\
        
    """
}
        
        
process STAR_ALIGN_CONTROL {
    container 'quay.io/biocontainers/star:2.7.11b--h43eeafb_3'
    input:
    path reads_control_1
    path reads_control_2
    path star_index

    output:
    path 'controlReadsPerGene.out.tab' 

    script:
    """
    STAR --runThreadN 8 --genomeDir $star_index \\
         --readFilesIn $reads_control_1 $reads_control_2 \\
         --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate \\
         --quantMode GeneCounts \\
         --outFileNamePrefix control 
    """
        
}

process STAR_ALIGN_TREATMENT {
    container 'quay.io/biocontainers/star:2.7.11b--h43eeafb_3'
    input:
    path reads_treatment_1
    path reads_treatment_2
    path star_index

    output:
    path 'treatmentReadsPerGene.out.tab' 

    script:
    """
    STAR --runThreadN 8 --genomeDir $star_index \\
         --readFilesIn $reads_treatment_1 $reads_treatment_2 \\
         --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate \\
         --quantMode GeneCounts \\
         --outFileNamePrefix treatment 
    """
        
}


process DESEQ {
    container 'quay.io/biocontainers/bioconductor-deseq2:1.42.0--r43hf17093f_2'
    input:
    path control_reads_ch
    path treatment_reads_ch
    

    output:
    path "deseq2_results.csv"

    script:
    """
    Rscript -e '
    library(DESeq2)
    control_reads <- read.table("${control_reads_ch}", header=FALSE)
    treatment_reads <- read.table("${treatment_reads_ch}", header=FALSE)
    combined_counts <- cbind(control_reads[,4], treatment_reads[,4])
    colnames(combined_counts) <- c('Control', 'Treatment')
    rownames(combined_counts) <- control_reads[,1]
    coldata <- data.frame(condition=factor(c('Control', 'Treatment')))
    dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=combined_counts, colData=coldata, design=~condition)
    dds <- DESeq(dds)
    results <- results(dds)
    write.csv(as.data.frame(results), 'deseq2_results.csv')
    '
    """
}


workflow {
    control1_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.reads_control_1)
    control2_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.reads_control_2)
    treatment1_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.reads_treatment_1)
    treatment2_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.reads_treatment_2)

    FASTQC(control1_ch, control2_ch, treatment1_ch, treatment2_ch)

    genome_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.genome)
    gtf_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.gtf)
    
    star_index = STARINDEX(genome_ch, gtf_ch)

    control_reads_ch = STAR_ALIGN_CONTROL(control1_ch, control2_ch, star_index)
    treatment_reads_ch = STAR_ALIGN_TREATMENT(treatment1_ch, treatment2_ch, star_index)
    
    DESEQ(control_reads_ch, treatment_reads_ch)
}


error message is this:
executor >  local (1)
[a8/3867b4] FASTQC (1)               [100%] 1 of 1, cached: 1 ✔
[de/6d9fd1] STARINDEX (1)            [100%] 1 of 1, cached: 1 ✔
[b2/f65897] STAR_ALIGN_CONTROL (1)   [100%] 1 of 1, cached: 1 ✔
[8b/0532f4] STAR_ALIGN_TREATMENT (1) [100%] 1 of 1, cached: 1 ✔
[71/95d291] DESEQ (1)                [  0%] 0 of 1
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'DESEQ (1)'

Caused by:
  Process `DESEQ (1)` terminated with an error exit status (1)


Command executed:

  Rscript -e '
  library(DESeq2)
  control_reads <- read.table("controlReadsPerGene.out.tab", header=FALSE)
  treatment_reads <- read.table("treatmentReadsPerGene.out.tab", header=FALSE)
  combined_counts <- cbind(control_reads[,4], treatment_reads[,4])
  colnames(combined_counts) <- c('Control', 'Treatment')
  rownames(combined_counts) <- control_reads[,1]
  coldata <- data.frame(condition=factor(c('Control', 'Treatment')))
  dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=combined_counts, colData=coldata, design=~condition)
  dds <- DESeq(dds)
  results <- results(dds)
  write.csv(as.data.frame(results), 'deseq2_results.csv')
  '

Command exit status:
  1

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  
      expand.grid, I, unname
  
  Loading required package: IRanges
  Loading required package: GenomicRanges
  Loading required package: GenomeInfoDb
  Loading required package: SummarizedExperiment
  Loading required package: MatrixGenerics
  Loading required package: matrixStats
  
  Attaching package: ‘MatrixGenerics’
  
  The following objects are masked from ‘package:matrixStats’:
  
      colAlls, colAnyNAs, colAnys, colAvgsPerRowSet, colCollapse,
      colCounts, colCummaxs, colCummins, colCumprods, colCumsums,
      colDiffs, colIQRDiffs, colIQRs, colLogSumExps, colMadDiffs,
      colMads, colMaxs, colMeans2, colMedians, colMins, colOrderStats,
      colProds, colQuantiles, colRanges, colRanks, colSdDiffs, colSds,
      colSums2, colTabulates, colVarDiffs, colVars, colWeightedMads,
      colWeightedMeans, colWeightedMedians, colWeightedSds,
      colWeightedVars, rowAlls, rowAnyNAs, rowAnys, rowAvgsPerColSet,
      rowCollapse, rowCounts, rowCummaxs, rowCummins, rowCumprods,
      rowCumsums, rowDiffs, rowIQRDiffs, rowIQRs, rowLogSumExps,
      rowMadDiffs, rowMads, rowMaxs, rowMeans2, rowMedians, rowMins,
      rowOrderStats, rowProds, rowQuantiles, rowRanges, rowRanks,
      rowSdDiffs, rowSds, rowSums2, rowTabulates, rowVarDiffs, rowVars,
      rowWeightedMads, rowWeightedMeans, rowWeightedMedians,
      rowWeightedSds, rowWeightedVars
  
  Loading required package: Biobase
  Welcome to Bioconductor
  
      Vignettes contain introductory material; view with
      'browseVignettes()'. To cite Bioconductor, see
      'citation("Biobase")', and for packages 'citation("pkgname")'.
  
  
  Attaching package: ‘Biobase’
  
  The following object is masked from ‘package:MatrixGenerics’:
  
      rowMedians
  
  The following objects are masked from ‘package:matrixStats’:
  
      anyMissing, rowMedians
executor >  local (1)
[a8/3867b4] FASTQC (1)               [100%] 1 of 1, cached: 1 ✔
[de/6d9fd1] STARINDEX (1)            [100%] 1 of 1, cached: 1 ✔
[b2/f65897] STAR_ALIGN_CONTROL (1)   [100%] 1 of 1, cached: 1 ✔
[8b/0532f4] STAR_ALIGN_TREATMENT (1) [100%] 1 of 1, cached: 1 ✔
[71/95d291] DESEQ (1)                [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✘
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'DESEQ (1)'

Caused by:
  Process `DESEQ (1)` terminated with an error exit status (1)


Command executed:

  Rscript -e '
  library(DESeq2)
  control_reads <- read.table("controlReadsPerGene.out.tab", header=FALSE)
  treatment_reads <- read.table("treatmentReadsPerGene.out.tab", header=FALSE)
  combined_counts <- cbind(control_reads[,4], treatment_reads[,4])
  colnames(combined_counts) <- c('Control', 'Treatment')
  rownames(combined_counts) <- control_reads[,1]
  coldata <- data.frame(condition=factor(c('Control', 'Treatment')))
  dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=combined_counts, colData=coldata, design=~condition)
  dds <- DESeq(dds)
  results <- results(dds)
  write.csv(as.data.frame(results), 'deseq2_results.csv')
  '

Command exit status:
  1

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  
      expand.grid, I, unname
  
  Loading required package: IRanges
  Loading required package: GenomicRanges
  Loading required package: GenomeInfoDb
  Loading required package: SummarizedExperiment
  Loading required package: MatrixGenerics
  Loading required package: matrixStats
  
  Attaching package: ‘MatrixGenerics’
  
  The following objects are masked from ‘package:matrixStats’:
  
      colAlls, colAnyNAs, colAnys, colAvgsPerRowSet, colCollapse,
      colCounts, colCummaxs, colCummins, colCumprods, colCumsums,
      colDiffs, colIQRDiffs, colIQRs, colLogSumExps, colMadDiffs,
      colMads, colMaxs, colMeans2, colMedians, colMins, colOrderStats,
      colProds, colQuantiles, colRanges, colRanks, colSdDiffs, colSds,
      colSums2, colTabulates, colVarDiffs, colVars, colWeightedMads,
      colWeightedMeans, colWeightedMedians, colWeightedSds,
      colWeightedVars, rowAlls, rowAnyNAs, rowAnys, rowAvgsPerColSet,
      rowCollapse, rowCounts, rowCummaxs, rowCummins, rowCumprods,
      rowCumsums, rowDiffs, rowIQRDiffs, rowIQRs, rowLogSumExps,
      rowMadDiffs, rowMads, rowMaxs, rowMeans2, rowMedians, rowMins,
      rowOrderStats, rowProds, rowQuantiles, rowRanges, rowRanks,
      rowSdDiffs, rowSds, rowSums2, rowTabulates, rowVarDiffs, rowVars,
      rowWeightedMads, rowWeightedMeans, rowWeightedMedians,
      rowWeightedSds, rowWeightedVars
  
  Loading required package: Biobase
  Welcome to Bioconductor
  
      Vignettes contain introductory material; view with
      'browseVignettes()'. To cite Bioconductor, see
      'citation("Biobase")', and for packages 'citation("pkgname")'.
  
  
  Attaching package: ‘Biobase’
  
  The following object is masked from ‘package:MatrixGenerics’:
  
      rowMedians
  
  The following objects are masked from ‘package:matrixStats’:
  
      anyMissing, rowMedians
  
  Error: object 'Control' not found
  Execution halted

Work dir:
  /workspace/gitpod/nf-training/work/71/95d29139c22a8e39e3115921f42ba1

Container:
  quay.io/biocontainers/bioconductor-deseq2:1.42.0--r43hf17093f_2

Tip: you can replicate the issue by changing to the process work dir and entering the command `bash .command.run`

 -- Check '.nextflow.log' file for details


In your output, the Command executed: shows correct substitution of the files coming from output channels of STAR_ALIGN_CONTROL & STAR_ALIGN_TREATMENT.
So it seems that might not be the issue. Can you provide the contents of the work directory of DESEQ process? If the files are present in the work dir, it might be unrelated to channels passing the files incorrectly and might be Rscript problem.
  Error: object 'Control' not found
  Execution halted

